# Python how to batch printing x lines at a time in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, indexing, printing, range

I tried all sorts of for loops but just can't seem to figure out how to print "n" number of lines from a dictionary at a time. I am new to programming so please pardon my terminology and expressions...

**Example source:**

```
{'majorkey1': [{'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet'},
 {'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet'},
 {'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet'}],
 'majorkey2':[{'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet'},
 {'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet'},
 {'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet'}]}
```

**This prints everything at once (undesired):**

```
for majorkey in readerObj.keys():
    for idx, line in enumerate(readerObj.get(majorkey)):
        print line

 {'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet'}
 {'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet'}
 {'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet'}
 {'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet'}
 {'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet'}
 {'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet'}
```

I have gutted a lot of code to make this easier to read. The behaviour I would like is to print according to the number of lines specified. For now I will just use **lines_to_execute=2**. I would like to keep code as close as possible to minimize me rewriting this block. From this answer once working I will modify code so that it performs something *chunks* at a time.

**Code block I want to stay close to:**
*Ill mix psudo code here as well*

```
for majorkey in readerObj.keys():
    lines_to_execute = 2
    start_idx_position = 0
    range_to_execute = lines_to_execute
    for idx[start_idx_position:range_to_execute], line in enumerate(readerObj.get(majorkey)):
        print line
        increment start_idx_position by lines_to_execute
        increment range_to_execute by lines_to_execute
        time.sleep(1)
```

For this example if I want to print two lines or rows at a time, output would look like the below. Order is not important as same 2 don't get executed more than once:

**Desired output:**

```
 {'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet'}
 {'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet'}
```

*One second delay...*

```
 {'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet'}
 {'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet'}
```

*One second delay.*

```
 {'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet'}
 {'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet'}
```

I hope this is enough information to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
import time

for key in obj.keys():
    lines_to_execute = 2
    pprint(obj[key][:lines_to_execute]) # that's all you need
    time.sleep(1)
```

Keep it as simple as possible.